# Prometheus which is run in docker-compose doesn't see configuration file from local folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus

I have a following compose file namesd docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  back-tier:

services:

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.36.2
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/:/prometheus/
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    networks:
      - back-tier
    restart: always
```

Folder structure looks like this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

prometheus.yml looks like this:

```
# Sample Prometheus config
# This assumes that your Prometheus instance can access this application on localhost:8080

global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'spring boot scrape'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:8080']
```

I've started it with

```
docker-compoe up -d
```

I have spring boot application started locally:
when I hit `http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus`

I see following(my custom metric):

```
....
# HELP greeting_time_seconds Time taken to return greeting
# TYPE greeting_time_seconds summary
greeting_time_seconds{class="com.tutorialworks.demos.springbootwithmetrics.GreetingController",exception="none",method="greeting",quantile="0.5",} 8.8064E-5
greeting_time_seconds{class="com.tutorialworks.demos.springbootwithmetrics.GreetingController",exception="none",method="greeting",quantile="0.9",} 0.022018048
greeting_time_seconds_count{class="com.tutorialworks.demos.springbootwithmetrics.GreetingController",exception="none",method="greeting",} 9.0
greeting_time_seconds_sum{class="com.tutorialworks.demos.springbootwithmetrics.GreetingController",exception="none",method="greeting",} 0.022103
# HELP greeting_time_seconds_max Time taken to return greeting
# TYPE greeting_time_seconds_max gauge
greeting_time_seconds_max{class="com.tutorialworks.demos.springbootwithmetrics.GreetingController",exception="none",method="greeting",} 0.0212423
....
```

But when I try to access prometheus

```
http://localhost:9090/
```

I don't see any `greeting_time_seconds` metric

So looks like prometheus can't gather my metrics.

I've checked `http://localhost:9090/config`

And it responds with:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  evaluation_interval: 15s
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - follow_redirects: true
    enable_http2: true
    scheme: http
    timeout: 10s
    api_version: v2
    static_configs:
    - targets: []
scrape_configs:
- job_name: prometheus
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 15s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: http
  follow_redirects: true
  enable_http2: true
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - localhost:9090
```

So looks like it doesn't see my config from local folder.

How can I fix it ?

### UPDATE

I've corrected volume in docker-compose file:
....
prometheus:
image: prom/prometheus:v2.36.2
volumes:
- ./prometheus/:/etc/prometheus/
....

And now `http://localhost:9090/`

responds with configuration I provided:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  evaluation_interval: 15s
scrape_configs:
- job_name: spring boot scrape
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 5s
  scrape_timeout: 5s
  metrics_path: /actuator/prometheus
  scheme: http
  follow_redirects: true
  enable_http2: true
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - localhost:8080
```

but prometheus UI doesn't return my greeting metric and offers only limited list of metrics:
[image]

### UPDATE#2:

according to advice of DazWilkin I've updated compose file with

```
version: '3.7'

#networks:
#  back-tier:

services:

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.36.2
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/:/etc/prometheus/
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
#    networks:
#      - back-tier
    network_mode: "host"
    restart: always
```

And after compose up I see that container is alive but URL localhost:9090 is not accessible now

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAtOE.jpg
```

Comment: IIUC the Spring Boot app is bound to the host's (!) network (on 8080) which is inaccessible by default to Docker Compose. Within Docker Compose `localhost` is defined to the current service. You probably want to use `network_mode: "host"` so that the host's network is accessible to the Docker Compose containers. Or, run the Spring Boot app within Docker Compose and reference it by its service name

Comment: @DazWilkin please check UPDATE#2:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I was able to find a solution:
In prometheus config I had to provide `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost`

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'spring boot scrape'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:8080']
```